# Multiple LED strips over Pi4

Tags: python, adafruit

I am trying to control 3 LED strips independently over Pi using python.

As Pi4 only has 2 PWM channels, 0 and 1, I have only been successful in controlling 2 LED strips.

I even tried the software PWM for the strip but to no avail. My last option is to use an Arduino as a peripheral to the Pi and control the LEDs over Arduino.

I would be really thankful for any suggestions.

Thank You.

Comment: There are many types of LED strips.

Comment: https://www.adafruit.com/product/815 might help. 16 channel PWM driver for I2C.

Comment: @PMF - That is my last go to move. But thanks for the suggestion anyhow.